# Как реализовать запись в БД нескольких объектов из одной формы?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, на странице есть 100 блоков div(каждый блок - место в кинотеатре). При выборе нескольких блоков, создается массив в который записывается id блоков и отправляется в ruby переменную. Далее рендерится форма для добавления записей в БД.

```
<% if @test_test.present? %>
<% @test_test.each do |i| %>
    <div class="col-md-6 booking_blocks" id="<%= i %>">
    <button class="close" id="close" value="<%= i %>">×</button>
    <%= form_for(@place) do |f| %>
       <div class="field">
        <%= f.hidden_field :cinema_id, :value => @film_session.cinema_id %>
        <%= f.label :cinema_name %><br>
        <p><%= @cinema.cinema_name %></p>
      </div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :film_session_id, :value => @film_session.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :place_number, :value => i %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :session_name %><br>
        <p><%= @film_session.session_name %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :place_number %><br>
        <p><%= i %></p>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :status %><br>
        <%= f.check_box :status, class:"form form-control" %>
      </div>
      <br/>
    <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Booking", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

В форме выводятся данные из выбранных блоков [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать запись в БД сразу нескольких объектов из этой формы нажатием одной кнопки submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, что конкретно должно происходить. Но я бы не стал делать множество форм. На сколько я понимаю, `cinema_id` и `film_session_id` будут во всех этих формах одинаковые. Различаются только `place_number` и `status`. Если внимательно посмотреть, то станет понятным, что нам не нужны оба эти поля в запросе. Достаточно наличия массивов `place_number`. Таким образом мы получаем примерную структуру формы:

```
<%= form_for(@booking) do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :cinema_id %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :film_session_id %>
  <%= form.collection_check_boxes :place_numbers, @test_test, :dup, nil %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Структура очень примерная. Например вместо `@test_test`, где, как я понял, лежит просто массив чисел, я бы советовал использовать что-то более осмысленное.

Ну а теперь для это формы нам нужен объект.

```
class BookingForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :cinema_id
  attribute :film_session_id
  attribute :place_numbers

  validates :place_numbers, presence: true # должно быть выбрано хотябы одно место
  def save
    return false unless valid?
    # Здесь пишем код, который должен разложить данный по моделям
  end

  def persisted?
    false #только для новой брони
  end
end
```

Тогда в контроллере пишем что-то типа

```
def new
  @booking = BookingForm.new(cinema_id: @film_session.cinema_id, film_session_id: @film_session.id)
end

def create
  @booking = BookingForm.new(params.require(:booking_form).permit(:cinema_id, :film_session_id, place_numbers: [])

  if @booking.save
    redirect_to action: :index
  else
    render action: :new
  end
end
```

Ещё раз уточню, это только пример. Я не знаю твою задачу полностью. Скорее всего, его можно и нужно оптимизировать. И точно нужно дополнить.

Рекомендую к ознакомлению книгу `Growing Rails Applications in Practice`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду разбираться, но с cinema_id и film_session_id Вы немного ошиблись) Конкретно для этого кинотеатра и для этого кино сеанса эти значения будут одинаковы, но кинотеатров может быть несколько, а кино сеансов десятки. Данные введены для того, что-бы различать на какой сеанс и в каком кинотеатре забронировано место.

Comment: @MaximCherevatov, я имею ввиду, может ли пользователь за один раз отправить запрос с несколькими `cinema_id` и `film_session_id`? Просто в моём представлении, бронирование (это ведь бронирование?) происходит на конкретный сеанс и конкретный кинотеатр. Чтобы забронировать места в другой зал - надо перейти на страницу того зала. Если такой подход ошибочен, боюсь мой ответ совсем неверен :(.

Comment: нет, Вы все правильно поняли! Спасибо)